# How can I manually place components in a FlowLayout or a GridLayout?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, flowlayout

I am having trouble deciding which layout to use on a JPanel. I need the JPanel to look something like what I have attempted to draw here.

```
|-----------------------|
|       Some JLabel     |
|                       |
|  JLabel |JTextField|  |
|  JLabel |JTextField|  |
|  JLabel |JTextField|  |
|-----------------------|
```

I was thinking about using FlowLayout but I can't figure out how to manually set a component to be on the next row. I tried GridLayout and I have had some success but not quite what I was looking for. Here is the code for this JPanel I have so far if it helps.

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
JLabel description = new JLabel("description..");

JLabel label1 = new JLabel("label1");
JLabel label2 = new JLabel("label2");
JLabel label3 = new JLabel("label3");       

JTextField field1 = new JTextField(25);
JTextField field2 = new JTextField(25);
JTextField field3 = new JTextField(25);

mainPanel.add(description);
mainPanel.add(label1);
mainPanel.add(field1);
mainPanel.add(label2);
mainPanel.add(field2);
mainPanel.add(label3);
mainPanel.add(field3);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `GridBagLayout` to achieve this, but it might be eaiser to simple use a `BorderLayout`, placing the title in the `NORTH` position and placing another panel with the fields on it, using a `GridLayout` in the `CENTER` position.

Of course, the final result will come down to what you want.

Have a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for some more ideas and don't be afraid to use compound layouts

Comment: Thanks! I used a panel for the NORTH area and a gridlayout panel for the CENTER area of the main panel. I'll have to do some tweaking but I really appreciate your suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

You are never forced to just use a single layout manager. You can use multiple panels, each with its own layout manager.

However, in your case a GridBagLayout might be the easiest in this case. Start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to use GridbagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for working examples and an explanation of all the constraints.

Comment: Congrats on 100k - not sure I'd call `GridBagLayout` the easiest, among the most powerful...easy.... ;)

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice it had changed :) Agreed, GridBagLayout is generally not the easiest. I was also going to suggest a BorderLayout with a GridLayout but then you have resizing issues. I really wish there was an easier to use layout in the JDK for label/text field pairs.

Comment: A hybrid of `GridLayout` and `GridBagLayout` - the ease of use of `GridLayout` with filling options of `GridBagLayout` :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer, yes, I guess I meant a layout in which the components are displayed at their preferred sizes.